# Error while extracting Outlook mail from Excel

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I need to extract all the mails contained in a certain folder in the Outlook app. This is the code I used to connect to folder:

```
Set OutlookApp = New Outlook.Application
Set OutlookNamespace = OutlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set Folder = OutlookNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("XXXXXX")
```

And this is the loop I used to extract the mails:

```
i = 1
For Each MyItem In Folder.Items
    If MyItem.ReceivedTime >= Range("B1").Value Then

        Range("A3").Offset(i, 0).Value = MyItem.Subject
        Range("B3").Offset(i, 0).Value = MyItem.ReceivedTime
        Range("C3").Offset(i, 0).Value = MyItem.SenderName
        Range("D3").Offset(i, 0).Value = MyItem.Body

        i = i + 1

     End If
Next MyItem
```

The code was working properly but now, I started to receive the following error: *Object doesn't support this property or method.* On this line:

```
If MyItem.ReceivedTime >= Range("B1").Value Then
```

When debugging, it looks like the MyItem object is empty at that moment but the loop should not be running if that is true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like there is an item other than a MailItem? Something like a [ReportItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.reportitem) (Class: olReport ; 46) which doesn't have a `ReceivedTime` property. You can either physically check it or use `.Class` to solve this issue. You can read more about the class in [OlObjectClass enumeration (Outlook)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.olobjectclass)

Try

```
For Each MyItem In Folder.Items
    If MyItem.Class = 43 Then '<~~ olMail
        If MyItem.ReceivedTime < Range("B1").Value Then
            '
            '~~> Rest of your code
            '
        End If
    End If
Next MyItem
```